# Remove subfolder from WordPress URL using htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I've moved WordPress into it's own directory as per the instruction found on the WordPress support site.

I've got his working fine but the URL now shows `http://www.example.com/subfolder/` but I want it to show without the `/subfolder/`

I can't seem to get the htaccess to remove the `/subfolder/`

Here's my current htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mysite.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ subfolder [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should change `http://www.mysite.com/subfolder/` to `http://www.mysite.com/`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/subfolder/(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Curious, if you "added an addtional "/" at the front of subfolder" (ie. at the front of the `RewriteRule` _pattern_) then it would never have worked in a directory/`.htaccess` context (as stated in the question). (?) The slash prefix would only be required in a _server_ or _virtualhost_ context?!

Answer (score 0):

For future reference: I think the answer provided by Hareesh Sivasubramanian is better:

> I advice you against messing up the contents of the .htaccess file. Revert the changes that you've made to this file and follow the simple procedue.
>      1. Login to the admin dashboard.
>      2. Go to Settings > General
>      3. In the WordPress Address (URL) field type http://www.example.com/site
>      4. In the Site Address (URL) field type http://www.example.com
>      Save the changes and you should be good to go.

(https://stackoverflow.com/a/37346685/1334353)