# Re-write codes not working in HTACCESS file;

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

before this thread is marked as a "**duplicate**", or down-voted by someone eager.......kindly allow me to address my issue first  :)

Despite having dozens of various solutions to this issue online, none seem to work for me.

I'm trying to hide a folder, so it does not display in my URL.

My domain name is : **www.example.com**

My login file is within the "**PHP**" folder.

So, the login URL is :  **www.example.com/PHP/login.php**

I am trying to hide the "**PHP**", so the URL displays as :

**www.example.com/login.php**

I've copy-pasted several examples from this forum, but nothing seems to work.

I've tried this :

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/PHP/
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /PHP/$1
```

or this.........

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/PHP
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ PHP/ $1
```

(i.e., I removed the trailing slashes)

Nothing works.  The URL continues to load normally.

The only time I get an error is when I include the "**[L]**" at the end of the code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/PHP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /PHP/ $1 [L]
```

Then, I get a "**403**" error..........which makes sense, seeing as the "[L]"  prevents any further Re-write commands from executing. And I have a few of them in my HTACCESS file.

Here is my complete HTACCESS file :

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteBase /

 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
 RewriteRule ^/PHP/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

 #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^PHP/
 #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ PHP/$1 [L]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

(Note the two lines which are **commented-out**. )

Comment: maybe you have not enabled the rewrite module for apache. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2 try `a2enmod rewrite` and restart apache

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove subfolder from WordPress URL using htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22301752/remove-subfolder-from-wordpress-url-using-htaccess)

Comment: Re-write module is enabled.  I have other codes in my HTACCESS file, and they all work perfectly.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/PHP$` or   `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/PHP/(.*)$`???

Comment: I already tried both ways.  I have updated my post, to show my full HTACCESS file

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try and see if it works for you.

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} [A-Z]{3,}\ /PHP/([^&\ ]+)
  RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]
```

Adding it with your current rules.

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteBase /

 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} [A-Z]{3,}\ /PHP/([^&\ ]*)
 RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/PHP [NC] 
 RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /PHP/$1.php [L]

 RewriteRule ^/?$ /PHP/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, Panama Jack.  It worked.  the PHP folder was removed from the URL....................but.............I got a 404-error :  FILE NOT FOUND.

Comment: Where did you place the rules?

Comment: I simply copy-pasted your example.  Exactly as you wrote it  (the entire HTACCESS file).

Comment: Is it possible that the the problem lies with one of these :   [R=301,L]................or............[L,R=301]  ?

Comment: Do you just want to redirect login.php or is there anything else you need to redirect in php folder?

Comment: I simply want to hide the PHP folder from view.    the login.php is inside the PHP folder.   As I stated :  I want my URL to say :   www.example.com/login.php   (well, actually, as you can see from my HTACCESS file,  I already removed all php file extensions; but, that is irrelevant to the current issue)

Comment: Ok so you just wanted to remove php folder if some one enters http://example.com/php/login.php? I see you hide php extention but not for the php folder.

Comment: Yes.  As I stated in my post :  I simply want to remove the PHP folder from view :   www.example.com/login.php.......................

Comment: I edited my anewer. I just left the part that removed the php folder if php folder is in the url.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78222/discussion-between-phpnewbie2015-and-panama-jack).

Comment: Hi Panama
still getting the 404 error
Here is what I am going to do : I will put the PHP folder inside another folder, and see if that helps :
www.example.com/FOLDER/PHP/login.php
Nope. Still not helping
:(

Comment: Its getting a 404 because you don't have a rule to handle rewriting it to the php folder. Your other rules are picking it up. You have a lot of stuff going on.  Are you also running wordpress?

Comment: No I am not running wordpress