# Dynamically redirect to subfolder using .htaccess, hide subfolder in url without using domain name

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a subfolder I want to redirect to, I want it to redirect dynamically so anytime I go to:

`example.domain/about` it takes me to `example.domain/subfolder/about`, but still shows: `example.domain/about`in the address bar

However, I don't want to have to specify a domain name so I can use it in any project. So I suppose just automatically want to declare the root domain name as a variable?

---

I have this working here:

```
RewriteRule !^subfolder/ /subfolder%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

And it doesn't require the domain name, but it still shows `subfolder` in the domain name.

---

The strategy in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22301752/remove-subfolder-from-wordpress-url-using-htaccess) answer is what I need, but minus the domain name:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/subfolder/(.*)$ http://www.example.domain/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I also need it to work for both the `www.` and the naked domain.

Comment: Try to remove `R=301` which is for redirecting it to the `destination` rule

Comment: Thanks guys, that works for the index file e.g. when I go to `/`, but it doesn't seem to work for any `/other` page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following rule :

```
RewriteEngine On
#remov php exten
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/subfolder/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder%{REQUEST_URI}.php [NC,L]
#redirect root to sub
RewriteRule ^((?!subfolder).*) /subfolder%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

Comment: That works! Thank you :) Is there a way I can combine that with not requiring `.php` extension? I'm using `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]`

Comment: Oh, actually is there anyway to override it for script, image and stylesheet paths that are in the root? Or is the only way to move these into the subfolder?