# wordpress .htaccess overwriting root .htaccess URL rewrite

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

Before I start, Here is my directory structure for my website

```
public_html 
    |-api
    |-main_site
```

So what I have tried to do is make any rewrite rule url that don't have the `/api` directory at the start of the URI, and to rewrite into the main_site directory(ex: going to `/img/kitten.jpg` would actually be going to `/main_site/img/kitten.jpg`). effectivly i have my website in the `/main_site/` but i don't want that subdirectory to be show in the URL.

I did this successfully with a .htaccess file in the root directory:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
# folders in public HTML to not be effected by the rewrite
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/bonfire/

# Rewrites all URLS 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?placeholderdomain\.
# Rewrite all those to insert /folder 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /main_site/$1 [L]
```

but then I installed wordpress into the main_site directory and wordpress's .htaccess file is causing the ``/main_site/``` part of to be revealed in the URL.

Here is the contents of my public_html .htaccess file:
and here is wordpress's .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /main_site/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /main_site/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

what can i do to prevent wordpress from redirecting at the root level, and making sure `/main_site/` does not appear in the URL in wordpress's .htaccess?

Comment: The WordPress `.htaccess` file could be simplified slightly, but otherwise it looks OK. There is no redirect here. However, have you configured WordPress itself to omit the `/main_site` subdirectory from the URL in settings?

Comment: Maybe this one helps https://stackoverflow.com/q/37346476/1741542