# Removing subdirectory from Wordpress URL

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have my website on example.com (costom CMS) and Wordpress installation on /articles/

Normally, Wordpress boog can only be accessed via example.com/articles/post-name/
But what I want the URL to be example.com/post-name/ 
There should be no mention of /articles/ directory.

The custom CMS has only one page - index.php and all other pages would be on Wordpress

I tried adding some codes on .htaccess and although it worked for all the pages, it broke my front page which should show the custom CMS but instead shows the Wordpress front page.

.htaccess code:

```
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ articles/$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Example.com should point to the custom CMS, only the subpages should point to Wordpress but with my code, example.com open the front page of Wordpress blog.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove subfolder from WordPress URL using htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22301752/remove-subfolder-from-wordpress-url-using-htaccess)

Comment: @AnkurTiwari That doesn't solve my issue. I don't want the front page to point to Wordpress, only the inner pages. My code works for the inner pages.